# Meaning of statistical significance regarding categorial variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I've got a dataset that looks as follows:

```
    Species  Weight Length1 Length2 Length3 Height  Width
97  Perch   225.0   22.0    24.0    25.5    7.2930  3.7230
98  Perch   145.0   22.0    24.0    25.5    6.3750  3.8250
99  Perch   188.0   22.6    24.6    26.2    6.7334  4.1658
100 Perch   180.0   23.0    25.0    26.5    6.4395  3.6835
101 Perch   197.0   23.5    25.6    27.0    6.5610  4.2390
102 Perch   218.0   25.0    26.5    28.0    7.1680  4.1440
103 Perch   300.0   25.2    27.3    28.7    8.3230  5.1373
104 Perch   260.0   25.4    27.5    28.9    7.1672  4.3350
105 Perch   265.0   25.4    27.5    28.9    7.0516  4.3350
106 Perch   250.0   25.4    27.5    28.9    7.2828  4.5662
107 Perch   250.0   25.9    28.0    29.4    7.8204  4.2042
108 Perch   300.0   26.9    28.7    30.1    7.5852  4.6354
109 Perch   320.0   27.8    30.0    31.6    7.6156  4.7716
110 Perch   514.0   30.5    32.8    34.0    10.0300 6.0180
111 Perch   556.0   32.0    34.5    36.5    10.2565 6.3875
112 Perch   840.0   32.5    35.0    37.3    11.4884 7.7957
113 Perch   685.0   34.0    36.5    39.0    10.8810 6.8640
114 Perch   700.0   34.0    36.0    38.3    10.6091 6.7408
115 Perch   700.0   34.5    37.0    39.4    10.8350 6.2646
116 Perch   690.0   34.6    37.0    39.3    10.5717 6.3666
117 Perch   900.0   36.5    39.0    41.4    11.1366 7.4934
118 Perch   650.0   36.5    39.0    41.4    11.1366 6.0030
119 Perch   820.0   36.6    39.0    41.3    12.4313 7.3514
120 Perch   850.0   36.9    40.0    42.3    11.9286 7.1064
121 Perch   900.0   37.0    40.0    42.5    11.7300 7.2250
122 Perch   1015.0  37.0    40.0    42.4    12.3808 7.4624
123 Perch   820.0   37.1    40.0    42.5    11.1350 6.6300
124 Perch   1100.0  39.0    42.0    44.6    12.8002 6.8684
125 Perch   1000.0  39.8    43.0    45.2    11.9328 7.2772
126 Perch   1100.0  40.1    43.0    45.5    12.5125 7.4165
127 Perch   1000.0  40.2    43.5    46.0    12.6040 8.1420
128 Perch   1000.0  41.1    44.0    46.6    12.4888 7.5958
129 Pike    200.0   30.0    32.3    34.8    5.5680  3.3756
130 Pike    300.0   31.7    34.0    37.8    5.7078  4.1580
131 Pike    300.0   32.7    35.0    38.8    5.9364  4.3844
132 Pike    300.0   34.8    37.3    39.8    6.2884  4.0198
133 Pike    430.0   35.5    38.0    40.5    7.2900  4.5765
134 Pike    345.0   36.0    38.5    41.0    6.3960  3.9770
135 Pike    456.0   40.0    42.5    45.5    7.2800  4.3225
136 Pike    510.0   40.0    42.5    45.5    6.8250  4.4590
137 Pike    540.0   40.1    43.0    45.8    7.7860  5.1296
138 Pike    500.0   42.0    45.0    48.0    6.9600  4.8960
139 Pike    567.0   43.2    46.0    48.7    7.7920  4.8700
140 Pike    770.0   44.8    48.0    51.2    7.6800  5.3760
141 Pike    950.0   48.3    51.7    55.1    8.9262  6.1712
142 Pike    1250.0  52.0    56.0    59.7    10.6863 6.9849
143 Pike    1600.0  56.0    60.0    64.0    9.6000  6.1440
144 Pike    1550.0  56.0    60.0    64.0    9.6000  6.1440
145 Pike    1650.0  59.0    63.4    68.0    10.8120 7.4800
146 Smelt   6.7 9.3 9.8 10.8    1.7388  1.0476
147 Smelt   7.5 10.0    10.5    11.6    1.9720  1.1600
148 Smelt   7.0 10.1    10.6    11.6    1.7284  1.1484
149 Smelt   9.7 10.4    11.0    12.0    2.1960  1.3800
150 Smelt   9.8 10.7    11.2    12.4    2.0832  1.2772
151 Smelt   8.7 10.8    11.3    12.6    1.9782  1.2852
152 Smelt   10.0    11.3    11.8    13.1    2.2139  1.2838
153 Smelt   9.9 11.3    11.8    13.1    2.2139  1.1659
154 Smelt   9.8 11.4    12.0    13.2    2.2044  1.1484
155 Smelt   12.2    11.5    12.2    13.4    2.0904  1.3936
156 Smelt   13.4    11.7    12.4    13.5    2.4300  1.2690
157 Smelt   12.2    12.1    13.0    13.8    2.2770  1.2558
158 Smelt   19.7    13.2    14.3    15.2    2.8728  2.0672
159 Smelt   19.9    13.8    15.0    16.2    2.9322  1.8792
```

Ran a linear regression using `Weight` vs the rest:  `model <- lm (fishdata$Weight ~., data = fishdata)`

Looking at `summary`:

```
(Intercept)          2.5e-11 ***
ï..SpeciesParkki    0.031152 *  
ï..SpeciesPerch     0.253419    
ï..SpeciesPike      0.125607    
ï..SpeciesRoach     0.260954    
ï..SpeciesSmelt     0.000268 ***
ï..SpeciesWhitefish 0.333045    
Length1             0.028403 *  
Length2             0.082653 .  
Length3             0.268633    
Height              0.688128    
Width               0.982832
```

I am just now studying regression so I am unsure how to interpret this. Looking at the data, `Smelt`'s weight is rather low. Why is it statistically significant?  I understand `length1`'s significance - The lengthier, the heavier the fish. But what am I meant to understand from the categorical variables?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have currently set-up your model this coefficient captures the  difference between the mean weight of Smelt fishes and  the baseline species (the one species that you do not have a coefficient for) keeping other factors constant. So it's not the weight but the weight difference.

In general significance depends on two things: coefficient size and standard error of that coefficient, where the latter depends on the standard deviation and sample size (of the Smelt species).

You're trying to disprove the null hypothesis that the difference between the mean weight of Smelt and the baseline species is 0.

Intuitively the probability of observing a difference of  0.0003 (grammes?) if the real difference is 0 is small BUT 0.0003 is not the same as 0, and if you're very certain of your estimate, indicated by a small standard error than you can still make confident statements that the difference is NOT 0.

You don't report a standard error in your question but my guess is that it's very small. If you have very many Smelt individuals or their weight varies very little that would result in a small standard error.

Bottom line don't confuse significance with coefficient size or effect size. Significance only tells you there is an effect, not how large (let alone how important) that effect is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, it doesn't indicate a linear connection between the two? Is that not what I was looking for?

Comment: As Demetri has pointed out in his answer if you use a categorical variable in linear regression the effect is not really a linear relation but rather a test of difference in mean weight for the species. The reason for that is how they are included. The variable is recoded into a number of variables that contain 0's and 1's.

Comment: "the latter depends on the standard deviation and sample size (of the Smelt species)": this is ambiguous, I want to stress that the st. deviation here is not the one of the Smelt species, but of all the residuals. Also, particular association of some species with other factors may play a role in raising its st. error.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, let's only examine three species (Perch, Whitefish, and Smelt) and how species affects weight.

$$ \mbox{Weight}  = \beta_0 + \beta_1 I(\mbox{species}=\mbox{Perch}) + \beta_2 I(\mbox{species}=\mbox{Whitefish})$$

Here, $I(x=a)$ is a function which is 1 when $x=a$ an 0 else. $I$ is called an indicator or identifier function since it identifies when the argument is equal to some value.

In regression, the intercept is equal to our reference group.  Our model does not have an indicator for Smelt, so that means that the intercept is actually the estimated weight for Smelt.  The coefficients of the indicators are then interpreted as the difference in weights between Smelt and the indicated species.

The null for these coefficients is that they are 0 (equivalently, that all species have the same weight).  The alternative is that they are false.  For categorical variables like Species, we are rarely interested in the coefficient of any one Species and instead we are interested in knowing if the variable Species tells us *anything* about the weight.  The way we do that is to perform a Likelihood Ratio Test in the case of a GLM or other statistical model, or an F test in the special case of linear regression.

You can perform an F test in R using the `anova` function. Fit two models, one with Species and one without Species, then pass those models to `anova`.  The p value returned is the p value for the F test.  If we reject the null of this test, this means that the residual variance as a result of including Species in the model is smaller than we would have expected had Species had no effect.  We would conclude that Species is a variable which can help explain the data.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. We haven't learnt ANOVA testing in class yet, can you simplify what you mean regarding my specific example?  From my understanding, you mean that the significance level shows that species, specifically Smelt can contribute to understanding the data?